# Need Help Configuring VLANs on SMC Managed Switch

Tags: switch, vlan

**Hello,**

I am in the process of configuring a new network layout for my computer repair business using a Cisco RV320 Router, SMC SMCGS26C-Smart managed switch and a D-Link DAP-2660 WAP.  My goal is to have 2 separate VLANs, one for internal business computers and one for computers being serviced so that I can have the service computers connect to the internet without having access to my business' systems.

So far I have been able to get the Router and WAP to separate connected devices into their appropriate VLANs based on the SSID that the client system connects to.  I am now trying to do the same with the SMC managed switch, but I am running into a wall with it.  I am new to VLANs and I think I am just having a mental block with the terminologies that SMC uses.

Here is my current configuration.

**VLANs**

VLAN ID 1 is default

VLAN ID 1001 is for internal business computers

VLAN ID 1002 is for service computers

**Router**

Cisco RV320

D-Link WAP is connected to LAN Port 1

SMC Switch is connected to LAN Port 2

VLANs are configured as described in the VLAN information above.

VLAN ID 1 DHCP is set to assign 192.168.100.X

VLAN ID 1001 DHCP is set to assign 192.168.0.X

VLAN ID 1002 DHCP is set to assign 192.168.1.X

[image]

Currently I am able to connect on ports 1 and 2 of the switch on the default VLAN ID 1 and get IP addresses automatically assigned in the 192.168.100.x range.  If I connect to any of the other ports I am unable to get an IP address assigned from the router.  My end goal is to have ports 3-6 on VLAN ID 1001 and have the router automatically assign an IP in the 192.168.0.x range and for connections on ports 7-26 on VLAN ID 1002 with the router automatically assigning in the IP range of 192.168.1.X range.

**Switch**

SMC SMCGS26C-Smart

Manual can be downloaded here: http://www.smc.com/en-global/download/downloadFile/353

VLANs are configured as described in the VLAN section above

Port 1 is intended to be a management port

Port 2 is connected to the Router (on Router LAN Port 2)

Ports 3-6 are for internal business computers on VLAN ID 1001

Ports 7-26 are for service systems on VLAN ID 1002

[image]

I'm pretty sure my settings on this page are where my problem lies.  I'm just not sure what I have configured incorrectly.
[image]

Any help that anybody here can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for this post. I realize this is an old post, but I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out the VLAN settings on this stupid SMC switch. This solved my problem.

Comment: Happy to hear this helped you.  I went crazy trying to figure it out.  I don't even remember how I finally figured out anymore.  The good news is this switch has been completely flawless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up figuring this out through trial and error.  Below are the correct VLAN port configuration settings for anybody who may come to this thread looking for an answer.

With this configuration connections on ports 3-6 are tagged with VLAN ID 1001 and automatically get a 192.168.0.X IP address from the RV320. Connections to ports 7-24 are tagged with VLAN ID 1002 and automatically get a 192.168.1.X IP address from the RV320. Connections on Port 1 are tagged with VLAN ID 1 and automatically get a 192.168.100.X IP address from the RV320.

[image]

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.